# AngularJS: failed to instantiate module

Tags: angularjs

I'm quite new to AngularJS, I'm struggling with following problem for a while now:

I want to use the resolve functionality of the routeProvider to load some data via a service.
But always end up with this error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module footballmvc due to:
>   Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module teams due to:
>   Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: Teams

This is my code:

**index.html**

```
...
<script src="app/app.js"></script>
<script src="app/config.js"></script>
<script src="app/services/divisionService.js"></script>
<script src="app/services/teamService.js"></script>
<script src="app/teams/teamControllers.js"></script>
<script src="app/divisions/divisionControllers.js"></script>
...

...
<body ng-app="footballmvc">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row" id="header">
            <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div id="menu" class="col-lg-2">
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                  <li><a href="#/divisions"><h3>Divisions</h3></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#/teams"><h3>Teams</h3></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="content" class="col-lg-10" ng-view>
                <!-- Content goes here! -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
...
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('footballmvc', ['config','ngRoute','teams','divisions'])
...
```

**teamControllers.js**

```
angular.module('teams', [])
.config(function($routeProvider, Teams, Divisions) {
$routeProvider
.when('/teams', {
  controller:'TeamListCtrl',
  templateUrl:'app/teams/list.tpl.html',
  resolve: { 
      teams : function(Teams) { 
          return Teams.query();       
      }    
  } 
})
...
```

**teamService.js**

```
angular.module('teams', [])

.factory('Teams', function($resource, config){
return $resource(config.MONGO_URL + 'teams/:id', {apiKey: config.MONGO_API_KEY,       id:'@_id.$oid'});
});
```

*****UPDATE: SOLUTION*****

Finally found the solution. Clue is to pass the dependency to the service only to the resolve function and not to the config function:

```
config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/teams', {
      controller: 'TeamListCtrl',
      templateUrl: 'app/teams/list.tpl.html',
      resolve: {
          teams: function (Teams) {
              return Teams.query();
          }
      }
    })
```

Comment: In your index.html, do you include all scripts (app.js, teamControllers.js, teamService.js)?

Comment: Can anyone explain why these parameters should go into a parameter's function instead of config itself?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to load the dependent scripts first. Namely, `'config','ngRoute','teams','divisions'` before you try to instantiate `app` module.

Also, you are defining twice the `teams` module.

```
angular.module('teams', [])
```

Should only occur once in your code. When you want to reference that module later on, use

```
angular.module('teams')
.config(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

This usually occurs when you have a missing script include on your index.html file or a mis match between you file name and the controller/service/module name.  Go back and double check your file names, file paths, and the actual angular names.

Answer (score 0):

That is angular telling you that it can't find the `footballmvc` module. The script is likely not included on the page, or there is some syntactical error somewhere preventing the module from being loaded/injected. Make sure your script paths are correct and there are no syntax errors before the `footballmvc` module is instanced in the DOM.